# How to cancel socket.io-client subscription in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, socket.io

I have an app in **TypeScript React** that uses **socket.io** client. The codes look like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const MyComponent = () => {

        const socket = io(WS_URL);

        const [ info, setInfo ] =  useState<string[]>([]);

        useEffect(() => {

                socket.open();

                socket.emit('get_info');

                socket.on('ws_reply', (msg:any) => {
                        setInfo(prevData => [...prevData, msg['data']]);
                }

                return(() => {socket.close()));

        }, []);

        return(
                <div>
                        {info}
                <div/>
        );

}

export { MyComponent };
```

When I run the site, the error below appeared at the second attempt when I visit the site (e.g. I when to another page of my application and then press back to this page). I have close the **socket.io** connection as above. But the error still seems to appear:

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

Comment: Can you please post the full code of the component? Thanks!

Comment: Alright, i have edited the codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try adding `const socket = io(WS_URL)` snippet into `useEffect()` instead.

See as the following:

```
const [ info, setInfo ] =  useState<string[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io(WS_URL);

    socket.open();
    socket.emit('get_info');
    socket.on('ws_reply', (msg:any) => {
       setInfo(prevData => [...prevData, msg['data']]);
    }

    return(() => {socket.close()));
}, []);
```

See this example: [Socket.IO, React and Node.js: implementing the React client](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/socket-react/#socketio-react-and-nodejs-implementing-the-react-client)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. You are right, moving **const socket = io(WS_URL** into **useEffect()** solve the error. May i know why this happens?

Comment: @CccAv The error message states that you can't perform state update until the component is not mounted. `useEffect` is about to do things once the component mounted, see from the documentation: *If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think of useEffect Hook as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount combined.* - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: Alright, thank you. I have only just started to use react not long ago. I'll read it up. Thank you.

Comment: @CccAv It's fine, everybody starts somewhere, that's why we have Stack Overflow to help each other!